# ReactJS Navbar not displaying correctly

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

Navbar displays weirdly and without any style

P.S : I'm pretty new to React.

I'm just creating a sample demo Navbar project. I followed the official code from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-mobile-friendly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ReactStrap</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

class Homepage extends React.Component {

render() {
        const appNavbar = (
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto" style={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"row"}}>
                        <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
                        <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav>
                        <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">Dank memes</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
    );

    return (
    <div>
      {appNavbar}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

[Expecting a Navbar but getting this mishmash:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxkr2.png)

Comment: Any error on console that you are getting on javascript console?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Might be issue with bootstrap.min.css file loading. Check in network if your bootstrap.min.css file gets loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bootstrap style is missing or not loaded properly. Did you install bootstrap:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

and import it in `src/index.js` file like below:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have installed Bootstrap using this command though:
`npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`

Comment: And can you try to import css in src/index.js file?

Comment: Importing the css to my `index.js` worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The page might be rendering before the css is retrieved from server and loaded. Check your network requests to see if the file was retrieved from the server.

Try saving the .css file in your local directory and import it for the app using,

```
import './css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

This will ensure that the file loads before the component is rendered.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this now and get back.